# Javascript and PHP won't play nice

Tags: php, javascript, arrays, forms

I have a group of checkboxes using this syntax:

```
echo "<form name=\"myform\" method=\"POST\" action=\"csvbuilder.php\">";
echo "<input type=\"checkbox\" name=\"list[]\" value=\"".$res['id']."\" />";
```

At the bottom I have a "Check all" button..

```
echo "<input type=\"button\" name=\"UnCheckAll\" value=\"Uncheck All\" onClick=\"uncheckAll(document.myform.list)\" />
```

Which refers to the following JS script..

```
function checkAll(field) {
  for (i = 0; i < field.length; i++)
    field[i].checked = true ;
}
```

Here's the problem:
The check all button only works when I remove the square brackets from the input name, ie `name="list"` as opposed to `name="list[]"`. I need the brackets, or else the PHP form handler won't work. I have tried adding the brackets to the JS, ie `onClick="uncheckAll(document.myform.list[])"` but that doesn't work either.

How do I get JS and PHP to play nicely?

Thanks to all responders. I especially appreciate any references/explanations/jfiddles.

Comment: Add a class to your input and uncheck the select boxes by their class is one approach. How to do this by a multi-select, I have no idea.

Comment: to make it look better try setting '' instead of "" inside the echo then you won't need all the `\\`. or use an HEREDOC

Comment: try adding a _reset_ button to the form `<input type="reset" value="Uncheck All"/>`, it'll do just what you need. Of course, if you have elements _other_ than checkboxes, they'll be reset, too

Comment: @eric.itzhak I'm not sure what you're getting at with all the quotes, but I'm just echoing one line at a time, I don't feel like that justifies a HEREDOC :/

Comment: @EliasVanOotegem Great idea! I don't know why I didn't think of that. Thanks! Unfortunately it doesn't solve the other half of my problem..

Comment: It  doesn't justify it, but you don't need all those slashes it just makes it harder for you to read later.

Comment: @eric.itzhak Oh I see what you mean.. I should use single quotes instead of doubles. You're right. Old habits die hard I suppose.

Comment: @Adelphia: Well, passing `document.myform.elements['list[]']` to the `checkAll` function will do the trick to check all checkboxes, and you can replace the `uncheckAll` function with a simple `reset` btn. I didn't read the entire question, just stopped after seeing an `onClick=uncheckall`. That's why I commented instead of answering :). Anyway: happy coding

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can be accessed with `document.myform['list[]']`:

```
echo "<input type=\"button\" name=\"UnCheckAll\" value=\"Uncheck All\" onClick=\"uncheckAll(document.myform['list[]'])\" />
```

Comment: Thanks for the simple solution

Answer (score 1):

You missed to paste `checkAll` button

JS function:

```
function checkAll(frm){
    var checkBoxes = frm.elements['list[]'];
    for (i = 0; i < checkBoxes.length; i++){
        checkBoxes[i].checked = (frm.CheckAll.value == "Check All") ? 'checked' : '';
    }
    frm.CheckAll.value = (frm.CheckAll.value == "Check All") ? "Uncheck All" : 'Check All';
}
```

OnClick:

```
echo "<input type=\"button\" name=\"CheckAll\" value=\"Check All\" onClick=\"checkAll(document.myform)\" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
function checkAll(fieldName) {
    var fields = document.getElementsByName(fieldName);
    for (i=0; i<fields.lengh; i++) {
        fields[i].checked = true;
    }
}
```

Then call this from HTML using the following PHP snippet:

```
echo "<input type=\"button\" name=\"UnCheckAll\" value=\"Uncheck All\" onClick=\"uncheckAll('list[]')\" />
```

Note that the `onClick`-function of the button now calls the `checkAll`-function passing the element name instead of the elements.